# Homology of compact symmetric spaces

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Could anyone point me to a table  giving the homology of all compact symmetric spaces, i.e. $G/U$ where $G$ is a compact Lie group and $U$ the fixed points of an involution of $G$?   I'd be happy even with rational coefficients, although
torsion information would be great.  Thanks.

Comment: what makes you think that this list can even be finitely generated? e.g. are you aware there being only finitely many involutions (modulo conjugation) for the sequence of groups $SO(n), n=1,2,3, \ldots$ ?

Comment: Yes, the symmetric spaces were classified by E. Cartan. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_space#Classification_result for the list.   However, I haven't seen anywhere a list of their homologies. Probably it was done in the 1950s, but I couldn't find it in e.g. the Borel-Hirzebruch papers.

Comment: Have you checked in a book like Joe Wolf's "Spaces of Constant Curvature"

Comment: Your question asks for $G/U$ where you've declared $U$ to be the fixed point set of an involution on $G$. This is much more general than Cartan's symmetric spaces. E.g. implies nothing about the quotient being locally homogeneous nor the involution being an isometry for the Killing form.

Comment: Probably <a href="http://mathoverflow.net/questions/78717/cohomology-groups-of-homogeneous-spaces">this question </a> is relevant.  Anyhow there is a book by Toda and Mimura (in Japanese, unfortunately) with a table of cohomology of classical homogeneous spaces.

Comment: Could I ask what application do you have this homology information for?